# Pull item receipt line item on custom record field

Tags: netsuite

I have a custom record that is used by quality team to acknowledge inspection against item receipt. Currently, they are manually selecting item receipt and then the item to be inspected from the full item list. I would like the item field to display only the shortened list of items ONLY from the particular receipt, once the user selects receipt number in the field. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible!

You can try creating a Saved Search and add in all the required fields from custom record and Item Receipt.

Later you can develop a Suitelet and create the field (which will be used by the User to select receipt number). Then you can pass it as a Filter to above saved search and display the results accordingly.

Let me know if you have any issues in comments below.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I am new to scripting and was trying to avoid it as much as possible but it seems that there is no easier way out in this case. Would you please elaborate on how to pass saved search value as a list on a custom field?